# How can I remove multi char after cursor in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to delete, say, 5 characters after cursor. How can I do it?

Just like <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> change 5 words, how can I change 5 characters?

Comment: `5x` deletes 5 characters

Comment: You're asking two different things. First you ask to _remove_ and then to _change_. If it's remove `5x` will do it. If you also want to enter insert mode (that would be change) you can `5xi`

Comment: @csum but I want entry input mode after delete,I need input something else, after finish input I can repeat all the operations by point .

Comment: `5s` does overwrite the next 5 characters

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're not just asking for removal, but also changing, and other stuff.

The point is that <kbd>w</kbd> is the text object that moves forward by words, whereas <kbd>l</kbd> is what moves forward by character, so

- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> changes the following 5 characters, (as per the comment, you can shorten this to <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>)
- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> deletes the following 5 characters, which you can shorten to <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

Similarly, just like <kbd>b</kbd> is words backward, <kbd>h</kbd> is characters backward, so you can do <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>, for instance.

Comment: `5s` is shorter ;-) I like this answer. I just want to add, that anybody having this kind of trouble should have a look at `:h left-right-motions`